# How to print function body with parsed variable

Tags: r, functional-programming

Suppose I have a function which takes some argument `k` and return another function which takes argument `n` but uses `k` in its function body.

```
makeFn <- function(k) {
  function(n){
    rep(k,n)
  }
}

five <- makeFn(5)

five(3)
# [1] 5 5 5

body(five)
# {
#    rep(k, n)
# }
```

How can I print the body of `five` so that it shows `rep(5,n)` instead of `rep(k,n)`?

Comment: How flexible of a solution do you need? Can there more levels of nested functions? For this simple case, you could use `substitute` with its convenient "env" argument. SInce `substitute` won't evaluate its first argument, we need to construct a call like `eval(call("substitute", body(five), environment(five)))`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to combine `eval` and `bquote`.

```
makeFn <- function(k) {
  eval(bquote(function(n) rep(.(k),n)))
}

five <- makeFn(5)
body(five)
# rep(5, n)
```

The `.()` notation is telling `bquote` to evaluate whatever is in the parenthesis, then include the result in the expression.